# no suitable conversion function from "const std::filesystem::path" to "char *" exists

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I'm a C++ beginner. I've been learning C++ for a week now.

I was messing around with the `<filesystem>` library, trying to learn new things. I tried to make a function to receive a path to a `.txt` file and reads the file contents to print it to the console. But, I ran into this problem which is in the title:

```cpp
using namespace std;
using namespace std::filesystem;

void read_file(char File[260]);

int main(){
    for (auto entry: recursive_directory_iterator("C:\\Users\\malar\\AppData\\Local")){
        try{
            if (entry.path().extension() == ".txt"){
                read_file(entry.path()); // no suitable conversion function from "const std::filesystem::path" to "char *" exists
            }
        }
        catch (filesystem_error){
            continue;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void read_file(char File[260]){
    FILE *rf = fopen(File, "r"); // rf = read file
    char Buffer[260];
    if (rf == NULL){
        cout << "File: " << File << " Cannot be opened\n";
    }
    while (fread(Buffer, 260, 1, rf) != NULL){
        cout << Buffer << endl;
    }
    fclose(rf);
    cout << "File Closed\n";
}
```

I've tried to fix the problem by doing type conversion, but perhaps I did it with a wrong type?

Comment: Your `read_file()` probably should take a `std::string` as the filename and not `char File[260]` and you should use ifstream for the file instead of the `c` language `FILE*` and `fopen()`

Comment: @drescherjm a better option would be to have `read_file()` take a `std::filesystem::path` instead of a `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `path::string()` first or `path::u8string()` for UTF-8 to get the path, and then you can use the `string::c_str()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your `read_file()` function expects a (non-const!) `char*` pointer (in a function parameter, an array like `char[N]` is just syntax sugar for a pointer like `char*`). You are passing it a `std::filesystem::path` object instead, but there is no conversion defined from a `system::filesystem::path` to a `char*`, hence the compiler error.

However, `std::filesystem::path` does have an implicit conversion to `std::wstring` (on Windows only, which you appear to be running on) or to `std::string` (on Posix systems).  It also has public `(w|u8|u16|u32)string()` methods, too.

So, in your case, if you make `read_file()` take a `const char*` pointer (which is what `fopen()` is expecting anyway), you can then pass it the return value from `entry.path.string().c_str()`, eg:

```cpp
void read_file(const char *File);
...
read_file(entry.path().string().c_str());
```

---

With that said, note that you are using C-style file I/O. If you were to use C++-style file I/O instead (ie, via `std::ifstream`) then you can open the file using a `std::filesystem::path` object as-is, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void read_file(fs::path File);

fs::path GetLocalAppdataPath() {
    char szPath[MAX_PATH] = {};
    SHGetFolderPathA(NULL, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, szPath);
    return fs::path(szPath);
}

int main(){
    for (auto entry: fs::recursive_directory_iterator(GetLocalAppdataPath())){
        try{
            if (entry.path().extension() == ".txt"){
                read_file(entry.path()); // OK
            }
        }
        catch (const fs::filesystem_error&){
            continue;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void read_file(fs::path File){
    std::ifstream rf(File);
    if (!rf.is_open()){
        std::cout << "File: " << File << " Cannot be opened" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::string Buffer;
    while (std::getline(rf, Buffer)){
        std::cout << Buffer << std::endl;
    }
    rf.close();
    std::cout << "File Closed" << std::endl;
}
```